# Why can't I use a LinkButton in the ASP.NET login control for the Login button?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, linkbutton, login-control

I lost a week of time on this.  I wanted to use a LinkButton instead of the standard asp button so I could attached a SkinID to it that I use for link buttons.  When using the linkbutton:

`<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Login" SkinID="loginButton"
                                    ValidationGroup="rgtLogin" />`

the anonymous cookie is never deleted and the Profile_OnMigrateAnonymous is called endlessly.  And since the cookie is never removed, my profile is never set to the correct user.

I changed this back to the regular asp button and it works like it should.  Does anybody know why I can't use the above code for the Login command on the Login control?  I need know to figure out how to apply my skin to a regular button.

Comment: use &nbsp; and give jacobs answer a tick mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a LinkButton works for me in our `Login` control.  However, I noticed that your LinkButton has no text.  I've often-times had problems with links working properly when they're completely empty.  Does your LinkButton work when filled with text, even if it's an `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Very weird - I added text to the linkbutton and it started working normally.  However, I don't want text, so I removed it.  And it still worked.  Works in all browsers now.  I wish I could explain why weird things like this happen and throw me off!  Thanks for the comment.